# global numpy array changes inside a function without global reference to it

Tags: python, scope, global-variables

Why can I change a global numpy array from inside a function without using a explicit global reference to it?

```
import numpy as np
def test():
    a[0,0,0] = 34
    print(a)

a = np.zeros( (3, 2, 4), dtype=np.int)
test()
print(a)
```

both print() are equal to:

```
[[[34  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0]]

 [[ 0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0]]

 [[ 0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0]]]
[[[34  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0]]

 [[ 0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0]]

 [[ 0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0  0]]]
```

This contradicts what [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function) here says.

Comment: Objects aren't global or local. Variables are global or local. The array is the same array, with two variables referring to it.

Comment: There is no contradiction. You can access a global variable just fine without a global statement, but any assignment will default to a local variable unless you use the global statement. Here you are simply referencing a global variable and mutating the object being referenced by that variable

Comment: So, actually, objects can be local or global and, when created locally, they are freed after their scopes vanish, but if you refer to an existing global object without creating a new one, it changes the global object.  So the key point here is knowing when each thing in Python is an object or not.